# What is a logical threshold in terms of users or devices to migrate from WPA personal to WPA enterprise?

Tags: wpa2, wpa2-psk, wpa2-eap, wpa-enterprise, wpa3

*I have a question in particular about WPA's **Enterprise versus Personal** without discussing the specifics of WPA2/WPA3.*

I've encountered quite a few situations where the Personal version of WPA2/WPA3 was used while WiFi access was provided to hundreds of devices or users. This seems to me as a situation where the Enterprise version should be preferred.

So, unless there is a regulatory requirement, when should a company most likely transition from the Personal version to the Enterprise version? When they have 10 users or devices, 100, or 300?

What is it actually that we want to prevent with the Enterprise version compared to the Personal version and why does it suddenly matter with a bigger user or device count and not with a smaller count? The increase attack surface? Are there other factors to consider? What is a general rule of thumb for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPA enterprise means that there are individual credentials per user, not the same one for all users.

This provides accountability, i.e. see which users are connected with which device at which time. This also makes it easy to disable access if someone leaves the organization without changing the commonly used credentials. It can also be integrated with other logins, for example using Active Directory.

In short: this is what a mature business needs which actually cares sufficiently about security. There is no clear number of users when this maturity level is reached.